# Asynchronous lookup over HTTP and checking the status

Tags: c#, error-handling, http, async-await

For some reason declaring `ApiResult` before checking if the answer is in a correct status doesn't look good. I wonder if there is any better way to check the status and return the result:

```
public async Task<ApiResult> GetCustomersByOutcode(string outcode)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ConfigureHttpClient(client);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(
            $"customer?q={WebUtility.UrlEncode(outcode)}");

        ApiResult result = null;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult>();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never wrote which language this is in. Looks like C#?

Comment: It is indeed. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to remove the `result` variable. You can just return the result. You don't have to store it in a temporary variable:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult>();
}
else {
    return null;
}
```

In this case I would even use the ternary `? :` operator:

```
return response.IsSuccessStatusCode
    ? await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult>()
    : null;
```

You could also write it like this:

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    return null;

return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult>();
```

Comment: but return null is not a bad practice? could we get rid of it?

Comment: Well, you can make a special subclass of `ApiResult` to capture the failure case. Usually it is also an alternative to throw an exception. However, since you are in an asynchronous context, I recommend the former.

Comment: @tribet I personally don't find `return null;` to be bad practice.  Can't speak for everybody here but there are others who agree.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` ? So it would be something like

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult>();
```